# Game Theory - Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

For this problem I was asked to find all Nash equilibrium by method of (weak) perfect Bayesian Nash equilibrium.

[image]

I got stuck almost immediately trying to solve this, can anyone explain this for me?

Comment: The SE community tends to frown on link-dependent posts. And you're not showing work. And the link seems to depict a sequential game, and the concept of Nash equilibria doesn't really apply to sequential games.

Comment: Usually, a perfect Bayesian Equilibrium (PBE) is a refinement of Nash equilibrium, so I'm not sure why the question asks to use PBE to find Nash.